# how to know if dates 10 and 25 is on saturday or sunday

Tags: vb.net

How can I figure out if the `dates 10 and 25` is on `Saturday or Sunday` on specific month in vb.net?

```
If dates is on Saturday then
  msgbox(cut off move to friday)
elseif dates is on Sunday then
  msgbox(cut off move to monday)
```

Comment: Do you mean that if the date is a Saturday, you want the cutoff date to be the Friday before?  And if it's Sunday, you want it to be the Monday after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the DayOfWeek property of the DateTime struct.

```
If dates.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday then
  msgbox(cut off move to friday)
elseif dates.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday then
  msgbox(cut off move to monday)
```

Comment: thank you sir. I didn't know that property exist. Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 1):

As Brendan Green points out, just compare the datetime's DayOfWeek property:

```
Sub Main
    Dim dateToCompare As New DateTime(2014, 5, 10)

    Dim cutoff As DateTime

    If dateToCompare .DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday Then    
        cutoff = dateToCompare .AddDays(-1)
    Else
        If dateToCompare .DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday  Then
            cutoff = dateToCompare .AddDays(1)
        Else
            cutoff = dateToCompare
        End If
    End If

    Console.WriteLine("The cutoff date is {0}", cutoff)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the broad explanation sir.